# Range Profile in Radar System

Tags: signal-processing, bandwidth, fft, radar, range-detector

I am slightly confused on the range profile I am obtaining from my SCFW radar dataset. I am understanding of how fftshift works in shifting positive and negative frequency components to be centered about the DC voltage. However, I am not sure if I am required to perform shifts on data that is not real-time data.

With our radar system, we collect voltage information from our receiver along a 8 GHz Bandwidth. That image is attached as "Amplitudes along Bandwidth". From there I perform an FFT of which is supposed to return to me range information. However, I get these large peaks at the ends of the graph when I do not shift the FFT.

Most radar signal processing chains perform an fftshift perform plotting, but do not explain why. I attached both images (shifted and non-shifted). I just need to know if the peak when I apply the shift is most likely my scatterer and why it is always located at the middle of the graph. I am conflicted on whether or not these ends are useful and cannot find too much literature on this phenomenon in the signal processing chain.

[image: Amplitudes along Bandwidth]

[image: Range Profile Non-Shifted]

[image: Range Profile Shifted]